# Proof of a functional inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

I am reading the lecture notes "Lecture Notes on the Course
“Entropy Methods and Related Functional Inequalities”" by Daniel Matthes.

https://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~matthes/lecpavia.pdf

On p.54, the inequality 
$$
\sup_{\Omega} u\le 1+\int_{\Omega} |u_x|dx
$$
is used. It seems this inequality holds for rather general $u$. My question is how to prove it?

Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: It seems to me that such an inequality cannot be true unless you impose severe restrictions on $u$. The reason is that if you replace $u$ by $u+C$ for some large constant, the right hand side remains the same and the left hand side can be made arbitrarily large.

Comment: @GReyes Yes, you are right. I find some restrictions: $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $u_x(0)=u_x(1)=0$ in the lecture notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is easy in the context of these notes, since $\Omega \subset\mathbb R$, and is similar to the main step in proving the usual Sobolev inequalities,

$$ |u(x)| =\left| u(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x u_x (y) dy\right| \le |u(x_0)| + \int_\Omega |u_x(y)|dy$$
Now, it is assumed that $\int_\Omega |u| = 1$. Since $|u|$ is presumably continuous, by an integral Mean Value Theorem, this means that there exists $x_0$ such that $|u(x_0)|=1$. Pick that one, then take a supremum over $x$. Toss away the absolute values on $u$, because its also assumed that $u>0$, and we have the result.

From the proof, some smoothness is required, and the following additional assumptions are at least sufficient:

- $u>0$
- dimension is 1
- existence of $x_0$ such that $u(x_0)=1$

Dropping the first assumption means you should have absolute values. (And if you don't, then you might run into trouble by considering $-u$.)

Dropping the last assumption means you should have $u(x_0)$ instead.

Dropping the middle one, you can use a directional derivative instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The author remarks on page 55 that, the proof is the continuous embedding of $H^1(\Omega)$ into $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @LCH Yes, this is a special case of the Sobolev inequality. The proof in higher dimensions is more or less the same and can be found in Evan's "Partial Differential Equations", chapter 5 (specifically chapter 5.6). Its a little odd to me that this book doesn't state the 1D results though. There is also Leoni's A First Course In Sobolev Spaces (Chapter 12)

Comment: The author mentions that the continuous embedding of H1
(Ω) into L∞(Ω) does no longer exist in two (or more) dimensions. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: That's correct, the general proof in higher dimensions shows that you have a continuous embedding into some L^p space. It turns out that to get $L^\infty$ you need more than dimension/2 derivatives